# how to replace grommets(snaps) on a coat

Tags: replacement

Zipper broke on an expensive coat. To replace they have to take off the snaps that go over the zipper and state they can't put back on.  This would leave holes in coat. Does anyone know of any way to replace these?

Comment: How is this a Home-Improvement DIY question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about home improvement.

Comment: As others have said, this probably doesn't apply to DIY but I can't find any other SE page that would be better.  With that in mind, I'm trying to think of any possible way that this makes sense to me.  Can you post pictures of the coat and specifically the zipper/snaps area?  Or at least the brand/design (does the term "model" really apply to coats?).  If I had to provide an answer based on the information given, I would say find a new tailor.  I don't have much experience in that area because my clothes aren't worth tailoring/repairing but I would think replacing a snap would be very common.

Comment: I agree but couldn't find any other place to post.  I'm currently in a car stuck in NYC traffic on way to MD appt with sister.  When I get home will be able to take picture, it is my son's jacket. A North Face/Supreme pd 600$. Zipper broke off when chair at work ran over it. The snaps are over the side of the zipper(cloth part), to replace zipper snaps must come off. My tailor said wouldn't be able to put them back on and it would leave holes.

Comment: To those that state not a home improvement question believe me, my home will be much improved if I find a answer to this question! Thank you

Comment: While I 100% believe that to be true (and that your comment is mostly in jest)the FAQ states that it is for "the structure, utilities, and major appliances." On to helping...I found this image of the jacket style.  http://www.supremenewyork.com/news/559/images?image=6 zooming in, it appears as though the snaps are probably through the zipper's "extra fabric" (no idea of correct term) that exists inside the coat which is why they have to be removed to replace the zipper.  I would still search for a new tailor in this scenario.  On a $600 coat, there HAS to be someone to repair them Esp. in NYC

Comment: You might also try here: https://www.thenorthface.com/help/warranty.html (this link also covers non-warranty repairs and has contact info for certified repair shops - but looks like you will have to mail it)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!the pic is very similar,his is all denim colored but you are spot on about the snaps.  Strange place to locate them, yes?  Regardless, you have saved the day with your kindness and willingness to help someone out....jacket to be shipped to North Face tomr.  Many thanks and a lifetime of good wishes!

Answer (score 1):

Probably not a home improvement but I have repaired several snap covers on my BBQ with a [kit](https://www.stecksstore.com/line-20-snaps-and-setter-kit-3630-00/) like this very easy to use only 10$ or so. You will have spares for around the house.

Comment: Thanks but they said it wouldn't work, the ad for the kit states, "not 8included 8s the hole punched for snaps to go through"